# How to keep lambda alive to listen result from other lambda

Tags: concurrency, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda invocation chain which means every lambda function is invoked by another lambda except the first one. Now I hope that the first lambda function cannot be invoked util the follow-up functions complete. Is there any solution?

PS: I hope that the first lambda function need to be invoked by SQS and the max concurrent is 3 e.g.

Comment: Lambda functions are triggered by events. So as long the events are not triggered lambda will not be executed. So you might want to work towards limiting the messages being published to SQS.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for your comment. I am a little bit confused that If I need limit the message being published, that is to say, I need get to know the concurrent situation in biz logic. If so, I think the SQS is unnecessary since it cannot act as a concurrent controller.

Comment: Can you explain how are you triggering the first lambda in the chain?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It is triggered by SQS event. Biz logic send messages to SQS and then SQS trigger the first lambda function. Since the first function executes very quickly and the follow-up functions execute very slowly, which causes the resource of the first function released for SQS to call without completing the follow-up functions.

Comment: SQS Triggered Lambda functions are asynchronous, so the business logic will never know when the entire lambda function flow is completed. You need to store the progress of the flow at some common store from where the business logic can read the status and send the next SQS message when progress is in Completed status. You also might want to explore AWS Step functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at AWS Step Functions. Copied from the [product page](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/):

> Using Step Functions, you can design and run workflows that stitch together services such as AWS Lambda 
>   [...] 
>   Workflows are made up of a series of steps, with the output of one step acting as input into the next. 
>   [Step Functions] translates your workflow into a state machine diagram
>   [...] 
>   Step Functions automatically triggers and tracks each step, and retries when there are errors, so your application executes in order and as expected.